# Where is the sender name for iMessages set? I need to change it on an iPhone 4 (iOS 5)

Tags: ios, messages

The sender id as it displays on the recipients iMessage is what I would like to reset. However, I cannot find where it is set on the sending device (iPhone 4). It seems to be device dependent as sending iMessages from my iPad 2 displays a different sender name although both devices use the same Appleid.

Answer (score 4):

I hope I understood your question correctly. Try this: go to settings>>messages>>caller id. Choose the email address that is associated with the name you want the recipients to see

Comment: Yep. If you set it to the Apple ID (or associated email address) you want to use, that'll be the "from" in every iMessage you send, and before long your iMessageable friends will be automatically configured to reply to that rather than to your phone number.

Comment: I have an old IPhone and when I go into Settings>messages> it does not show CallerID
but show preview or repeat alert or MMS Messaging or show subject field (they are all On and Off buttons Where do I go now?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that it's set in the contact for that person's AppleID/Email Address. Take a look in that persons info in `Contacts.app`.

Comment: I may not be asking my question clearly.  I am trying to modify the name the message recipient sees when I send them an iMessage.  If I send someone an imessage from my iPhone, the recipient sees it as coming from DANI.  If I send the same person an iMessage from my iPad 2, they see it as being sent by Bill.

Comment: @Bill I'm going to assume it's the same iCloud account. In that case, it's probably buried in the iCloud account settings. (same as your Appstore)

Comment: Hmmm.  Yes, same iCloud account.  I upgraded both devices to ios5 within an hour of each each other but never specified any names for the devices.  They have to be buried somewhere in the device but I can't figure out where.

Comment: Have you looked into the other person's phone? Maybe he has your email saved as both Bill et Dani.